# Not able to get previous group chat history using ruby xmpp4r

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xmpp, openfire, xmpp4r

I am using ruby xmpp4r library to implement multi user group chat application with openfire server. I have created chat room on openfire server successfully. If user joins into chat room with openfire credential it's not returning previous group chat history it returns only few messages for that I am using `add_message_callback()` method.

Below is the openfire Group Chat History Setting:
** Show Entire Chat History (Show the entire chat history to users joining a room.)-- True

What am I missing here ?
Anybody have sample code to get previous group history?

Answer (score 1):

I ran a Wildfire server (successor to openfire), this setting seems to be server side.  On wildfire admin console its controlled under Group Chat > History Settings. It has the following options there:

Don't Show History - Do not show a chat history to users joining a room.

Show Entire Chat History - Show the entire chat history to users joining a room.

Show a Specific Number of Messages - Show a specific number of the most recent messages in the chat. Use the box below to specify that number.